# Upgrade Ubuntu 15.10 to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I got a message to upgrade from Ubuntu 15.10 to Ubuntu 16.04.2LTS. I'm almost new on Linux, I'd like know if this is going to make me loose my configurations or rather data. I've used the command:-

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and had no problems, I haven't used

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I'd like to know before I do something I will later regret.

Comment: The dist-upgrade won't overwrite your user data.  You'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The dist-upgrade won't overwrite your user data. You'll be fine.  There's always a possibility that a kernel update can break something though, most notable (frustrating for new users) being graphics drivers, but even then your user data will be preserved.

As you're new to Linux it's a good idea to take an *image* of your system with something like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php). That way if something does go wrong you can quickly restore to a previous state.